# Android : spannablestring shows HTML tags issue

Tags: java, android, html, string, fromhtml

hi in my string im getting `<br >` after using spannable string

my text is `hi<br />@dry12 <br /><br />hi all<br /><br />@akjhv`

here is my code

```
 SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);
                    for (int i = 0; i < model.getMentionedUsernames().size(); i++) {
                        if (text.contains(model.getMentionedUsernames().get(i))) {
                            String usernameinList = model.getMentionedUsernames().get(i);
                            int startIndex = text.indexOf(model.getMentionedUsernames().get(i));
                            int endIndex = startIndex + model.getMentionedUsernames().get(i).length();
                            ss.setSpan(getClickableSpan("usernameRedirect","",usernameinList), startIndex - 1, endIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        }
                    }
                 
    normalpost_text.setText(ss);
    normalpost_text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    normalpost_text.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

i tried html.fromHtml also but it also didnt work

above code output is `hi<br />@dry12 <br /><br />hi all<br /><br />@akjhv` (showing proper linkable and clikable functionality) but showing br tags thats an issue

need help

thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the `HtmlCompat.fromHtml` api to handle spans.

Comment: SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(HtmlCompat.fromHtml (text); @DarShan i tried this but it doesnt worked :(

Comment: You should directly use `normalpost_text.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(text, flag))`